# Executar classe Java passando parâmetros para o Scanner

Tags: java, reflexão, scanner, runtime

BEstamos criando um campeonato de programação em Java e gostaríamos que os alunos fizessem um algorítimo que leia de um scanner e calcule uma determinada lógica matemática e devolva na saída do sistema.

Até este ponto OK. O problema é que estou tentando realizar um corretor automático para os algorítimos com isto preciso executar a classe java e pegar o retorno para saber se o calculo está certo.

O problema central é que os alunos utilizam o scanner, com isto não consigo passar os parâmetros. Com a classe `Rumtime.getRuntime().exec("java MinhaClasse);` eu não consigo alimentar o Scanner, tentei substituir o System.in setando ele para um inputStream com um arquivo de texto criado por mim, mas não funciona pois está sendo iniciada outra instância do Java o o código não executa. Tentei buscar algo relacionado ao Reflection mas não encontrei nada ainda. Se alguém tiver alguma dica ficarei muito grato.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Escrevendo no processo filho

A forma mais simples de resolver o problema é recuperando o retorno do método [`Runtime#exec()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String-), que é do tipo `Process` e então usando o método [`Process#getOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream--) para conseguir escrever diretamente no *input* do processo.

Exemplo:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java MinhaClasse);
OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));
writer.write("Valor 1\n");
writer.write("Valor 2\n");
writer.write("Valor 2\n");
writer.flush(); // pode chamar várias vezes, dependendo do volume
writer.close(); // opcional, somente quando acabar a entrada
```

A quebra de linha (`\n`) após os valores servem para emular a tecla <kbd>Enter</kbd> que o usuário pressiona quando entra um valor para o `Scanner`.

## Cuidado com *buffers* e *deadlocks*

Algo **muito importante** é que sempre que escrever algo para o processo filho você **deve chamar o método `flush()` do `OutputStream`.

Isso ocorre porque o `OutputStream` pode ter algum *buffer* que pode não chegar imediatamente ao processo filho, deixando-o bloqueado indefinidamente.

E tal cuidado é ainda mais importante se o processo pai lê a saída do filho, pois nesse caso os dois podem ficar bloqueados indefinidamente.

## `ProcessBuilder`

Outra dica é que usar o [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) dá maior flexibilidade na hora de construir o processo filho.

Isso pode fazer a diferença se houver a necessidade de passar mais parâmetros ou algo mais complexo.

## Alternativa #1 - usando recursos nativos

Uma alternativa seria ainda usar o poder de linha de comando do sistema operacional e fazer o *pipe* para a entrada do programa Java a partir de algum arquivo texto. Exemplo:

```
cat input.txt | java MinhaClasse
```

## Alternativa #2 - usando um arquivo como entrada

Outra alternativa para a competição é não passar os dados via programação no processo principal. Eu acredito que isto poderia influenciar no tempo de execução do programa.

A ideia seria colocar o arquivo de entrada num diretório somente-leitura no disco e passar o caminho para este arquivo como parâmetro para o programa.

Depois, basta instruir os participantes a criar o [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.io.File-) com base num construtor que recebe um arquivo.

Exemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(args[0));
    ...
}
```

Muito mais simples, sem nenhuma dificuldade de implementação ou risco para a execução.

Comment: Muito obrigado, perfeito.